# Argument Cannot be null of requireValueInRange in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that works perfectly in some of my spreadsheets but fails on others.

Here is the code:

```
function depDrop_(range, sourceRange){
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit (){
  var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
  if (aColumn == 7 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
    depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
  }
  else if (aColumn == 8 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
    depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
  }
  else if (aColumn == 9 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
    depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
  }
}
```

This script works fine in some of my spreadsheets, but on others, it displays this error:

```
Argument cannot be null: range (line 2, file "Code")
```

Can someone help and explain me this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the line

```
sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
```

If there is no named range with the name matching the contents of `aCell`, sourceRange will be null and then you'll get an error when trying to build a validation rule with `requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true)`. So, check for that before building the rule. There are other, smaller issues that clutter the script:

- Checking for `&& SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` in each condition is pointless. If it was null for some reason, you'd have an error on the first line of `onEdit` function. In any case, it won't be null when `onEdit` trigger is called.
- The content of all three conditional statements is the same, so they can be combined.

Here is my version, which calls `depDrop_` only when the sourceRange is valid:

```
function onEdit (){
  var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
  if (aColumn == 7 || aColumn == 8 || aColumn == 9) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
    if (range) {
      var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
      if (sourceRange) {
        depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for that wonderful explanation, as far as the function of the script what it does is if I choose some value on column 7, an dropdown will be automatically created on column 8 based on the value on column 7, and on column 9 the dropdown will be depended on the value of column 8.